# Let $a$ be a real number such that $a > 0$. Show that the function $f : [a, +\infty) \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \tfrac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

Let $a$ be a real number such that $a > 0$. Show that the function $$f : [a, +\infty) \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$$
is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We want to find $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x-y| < \delta$ we have $\epsilon > \left\vert\frac 1x-\frac 1y\right\vert = \left\vert \frac{x-y}{xy} \right\vert$.

How about $\delta = \epsilon/a^2$?

Comment: yes, please can you continuou the solution till the end

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The derivative of $f$ is bounded, use MVT to show that there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$.